# Control does not switch to iframe in Selenium-Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, iframe, css-selectors

I am trying to scrape data from a news website and anytime a news article is clicked on, an ad shows up. I try to switch the control to the iframe to close the ad but it keeps on throwing "NoSuchElement" exception.

Below is the iframe that I want to switch to. The id is unique to this iframe.

```
<iframe title="Advertisement" id="ad_iframe" name="ad_iframe" scrolling="no" src="about:blank" frameborder="0" width="556px" height="222px" style="border: 0px; vertical-align: bottom; width: 556px; height: 222px;"></iframe>
```

My code is as follows:

```
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe[@id="ad_iframe"]')))
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="dismiss-button"]').click()
            
except NoSuchElementException:
    headline = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//section[@class='col-md-8 content']/h1")
    date = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//p[@class='small']")
```

The close button element is there in the iframe, and looks like:

```
<div class="ns-g3arv-e-19 button-common close-button" id="dismiss-button" x-ns-g3arv-e="19" x-overflow-forbidden="xy" aria-label="Close ad" role="button" tabindex="0"><div class="ns-g3arv-e-20" x-ns-g3arv-e="20" x-overflow-forbidden="xy"><span class="ns-g3arv-e-21" dir="auto" x-ns-g3arv-e="21" x-score="1">Close</span></div></div>
```

I am unable to find what is going wrong here? Why does selenium not 'switch' to the selected iframe?

Comment: Add a wait for the second element.

Comment: that iframe's src is a little odd.  (src="about:blank") It might be updated at a different time.  Selenium may not know it's actually "available" until later.  Might be worth checking to see if a sleep helps before getting the iframe element.

Answer (score 0):

### frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it()

[frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(locator)](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it) is the expectation for checking whether the given frame is available to switch to. If the frame is available it switches the given driver to the specified frame. It takes a *`locator`* as an argument.

As the element is within an [`<iframe>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447) so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52607451/7429447) for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

  - Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe#ad_iframe[name='ad_iframe']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[aria-label='Close ad'] span"))).click()
    ```
  - Using *XPATH*:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@id='ad_iframe' and @name='ad_iframe']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@aria-label='Close ad']//span[text()='Close']"))).click()
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
   from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
   from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
   from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)
- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)